# Unity for asp.net webapplication with class library

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, unity-container

I am using Unity in my webapplication project. I also have other library project ex. Presentation, Data. My Unity configuration is in web.config file.

My problem is I can not use dependency injection from one libary to another.
I want to inject property DataService from library Data in library Presentation in class PlayViewPresenter.

This is section fomr configuration file:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
        <alias alias="IDataService" type="Data.IDataService, Data"/>
        <alias alias="DataService" type="Data.DataService, Data"/>
        <alias alias="PlayViewPresenter" type="Presentation.PlayViewPresenter, Presentation"/>
        <assembly name="Data"/>
        <assembly name="Presentation"/>
        <namespace name="Data"/>
        <namespace name="Presentation"/>

        <container name="application">
        </container>

        <container name="session">
            <register type="IDataService" mapTo="DataService">
                <lifetime type="TransientLifetimeManager"/>
            </register>

        </container>
    </unity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was missing:

var container = Session["container"] as IUnityContainer;
    var presenter = container.Resolve();